# Javascript what does this mean

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I see this in Chrome debugger, unsure what `this: r` means exactly

```
this: r
$el: o.fn.init[1]
cid: "view1"
el: div#appview
results_collection: r
_byId: Object
length: 1
models: Array[1]
resultsList: r
$el: o.fn.init[1]
cid: "view2"
el: div#page.page
__proto__: s
constructor: function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)}
el: "#page"
initialize: function (){
renderList: function (collection) {
__proto__: Object
__proto__: s
__proto__: s
```

I have also seen this in underscore.js, `*sources` means variable length arguments?

```
_.extend(destination, *sources)
```

Come on people, I am asking here because I couldn't google anything meaningful, what's with all the hating, seriously.

Comment: The `*x` notation in the Underscore docs means "any number" so `_.extend` can be called any number of `source` objects to merge into `destination`. Presumably the notation is meant to mimic Ruby's `*` splats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It meant the value of `this` is an object of class `r`.

When you're looking at minified code, most variable, function, and class names are replaced with 1- and 2-character names, so they aren't very meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, any thoughts on `*sources` argument?

Comment: No, I'm not sure about that one. While JS functions can take variable length arguments, it's not notated in the function signature.